# Spark Context shutdown when I parallelize a large list

Tags: apache-spark

When I create an RDD from a list in Spark, it often causes the Spark Context to shut down as soon as I try to perform RDD operations on it.

Here is the code that causes the crash, and the stack trace is below. Any guidance much appreciated!

```
import sys

import numpy as np
import pyspark

SC = pyspark.SparkContext("local", "Crash app")

for i in xrange(10):

    randArray = np.random.rand(10**i)

    randRdd = SC.parallelize(randArray)
    print "Size of the RDD is ", randRdd.count()
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Generates this stack trace:

```
Size of the RDD is 1
Size of the RDD is 10
Size of the RDD is 100
Size of the RDD is 1000
Size of the RDD is 10000
Size of the RDD is 100000
Size of the RDD is 1000000
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7e69d839c2b5> in <module>()
      4 
      5     randRdd = SC.parallelize(randArray)
----> 6     print "Size of the RDD is " + str(randRdd.count())
      7     sys.stdout.flush()

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in count(self)
    706         3
    707         """
--> 708         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
    709 
    710     def stats(self):

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in sum(self)
    697         6.0
    698         """
--> 699         return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).reduce(operator.add)
    700 
    701     def count(self):

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in reduce(self, f)
    617             if acc is not None:
    618                 yield acc
--> 619         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
    620         return reduce(f, vals)
    621 

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in collect(self)
    581         """
    582         with _JavaStackTrace(self.context) as st:
--> 583           bytesInJava = self._jrdd.collect().iterator()
    584         return list(self._collect_iterator_through_file(bytesInJava))
    585 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.pyc in __call__(self, *args)
    535         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    536         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 537                 self.target_id, self.name)
    538 
    539         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.pyc in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o103.collect.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:639)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:638)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:638)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor.postStop(DAGScheduler.scala:1215)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.akka$actor$dungeon$FaultHandling$$finishTerminate(FaultHandling.scala:201)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.terminate(FaultHandling.scala:163)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.terminate(ActorCell.scala:338)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:431)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:447)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:262)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:218)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: Can you parallelize shorter lists successfully? At what length list does the context shutdown like this? Provide a script that others can use to reproduce your issue. That would be helpful. Finally, state what version of Spark you are using.

Comment: I've run into that error message, but check the log carefully, usually there is a failure way before that, of which the SC shutting down is usually just the consequence.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - I'm making an addition to the question to sow where it breaks down

Comment: @Nick Chammas: is there a simple way to check Spark version through python? My VDE is the iPython notebook, if that makes a difference

Comment: `SparkContext.version` or `sc.version` should give it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10000000 is a lot. I'm no expert on python, but while 1000000 of (what is it? integer numbers?) numbers can fit into average PC's memory, ten times more can't. I believe that your context is being shut down because of underlying memory issues.

Comment: The point of spark is that it can deal with this in parallel. I didn't make it explicit in the fragment above, but the code breaks on the .collect() step, not the actual creation of the array on one machine, so I think this is a spark problem. Actually a count() should just be a reduce job with minimal shuffling, so I don't see why the size should be a problem for it.

Comment: @StackG - Spark deals with stuff in parallel, sure, but `parallelize()` and `collect()` deal with datasets that can be contained just on the driver node. `parallelize()` takes something that must fit in memory on your driver node, and turns it into a distributed RDD. `collect()` takes an RDD distributed across the cluster and brings it all back to the driver node. So size definitely matters with these operations.

Comment: The Spark stack trace seems to be breaking on a `collect` statement. But I actually only called `count()`. I don't understand why Spark needs to collect to do a count - shouldn't each noce count it's chunk of the RDD, then return the result to the driver node to sum those? Collecting them all together seems to be taking away all the advantages of parallelization.

Comment: @StackG - `o103.collect` is not the same as `RDD.count()`. I don't know what `o103.collect` is--it has something to do with PySpark internals. But I think it is clear that the problem is you are calling `parallelize()` on something too big for your driver to handle.

Comment: With Spark 1.4.1, I get an error when working on the NumPy array with 100,000,000 (64-bit) doubles, i.e. for a ~1 GB array (on an 8 GB machine). The error is explicit: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space". Essentially, Spark has to store the split NumPy array in its own memory, and this exceeds its limits.

Answer (score 3):

range 10000000, may be crossing the memory limit... Spark by default create 4 partitions with parallelize fn and may be it's still not able to fit to the allowed memory limit. But if we increase the partitions like say to 10 (by giving it as parameter of parallelize fn) it may gets into the allowed range and is executed without any error. This is one of the other advantage of distributed programming.. :) hope i interpreted it correctly. Pls do review and correct if its not the case.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, I tried something like:

```
numPartitions = a number for example 10 or 100
randRdd = SC.parallelize(randArray,numPartitions)
```

Inspired by: [How to repartition evenly in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102013/how-to-repartition-evenly-in-spark) or here: https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/performance_optimization/how_many_partitions_does_an_rdd_have.html