# How to repartition evenly in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

To test how `.repartition()` works, I ran the following code:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(range(100))
rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

`rdd.getNumPartitions()` resulted in `4`. Then I ran:

```
rdd = rdd.repartition(10)
rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

`rdd.getNumPartitions()` this time resulted in `10`, so there were now 10 partitions.

However, I checked the partitions by:

```
rdd.glom().collect()
```

The result gave 4 non-empty lists and 6 empty lists. Why haven't any elements been distributed to the other 6 lists?

Comment: Which version of Spark do you use?

Comment: Version 1.6.1, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

The algorithm behind repartition() uses logic to optimize the most effective way to redistribute data across partitions. In this case, your range is very small and it doesn't find it optimal to actually break the data down further. If you were to use a much bigger range like 100000, you will find that it does in fact redistribute the data.

If you want to force a certain amount of partitions, you could specify the number of partitions upon the intial load of the data. At this point, it will try to evenly distribute the data across partitions even if it's not necessarily optimal. The parallelize function takes a second argument for partitions

```
    rdd = sc.parallelize(range(100), 10)
```

The same thing would work if you were to say read from a text file

```
    rdd = sc.textFile('path/to/file/, numPartitions)
```