# Partition RDD into two or more equitable RDDs with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, partitioning

I'm using PySpark and I'm looking for a way to partition an RDD into n equitable parts. Given :

```
rdd = sc.parallelize ([(u'28b195c271f', (u'm', u'50c41480')),
                       (u'_guid_UDeL9', (u'f', u'K0r_MuQH')),
                       (u'17503716353', (u'f', u'KUDRwaYm')),
                       (u'171f92200d6', (u'f', u'bdf53cb6')),
                       (u'_guid_NCw7S', (u'f', u'KSJakOd2')),
                       (u'331d8410d49', (u'f', u'1F37807A'))])
```

This is my code :

```
N = 2
repartionned_rdd = rdd.repartition(N).distinct().glom()
```

This is gives me two inequitable rdds.
**len(repartionned_rdd.collect()[0])** gives : 2 and **len(repartionned_rdd.collect()[1])** gives 4 ! Result :

```
[[(u'28b195c271f', (u'm', u'50c41480')),
 (u'_guid_UDeL9', (u'f', u'K0r_MuQH'))],
 [(u'17503716353', (u'f', u'KUDRwaYm')),
 (u'171f92200d6', (u'f', u'bdf53cb6')),
 (u'_guid_NCw7S', (u'f', u'KSJakOd2')),
 (u'331d8410d49', (u'f', u'1F37807A'))]]
```

What is the most efficient way to have as result two equitable parts (rdds), 3 and 3 as lenght.. Thx !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102013/how-to-repartition-evenly-in-spark

Comment: @Avihoo Mamka Thx but there is no answer :(

Comment: There is an explanation regarding the number of files. Did you try that on big number of files and got the same inequitable rdds?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are interested to the **randomSplit(weigths, seed)** [function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.randomSplit) that:

> splits this RDD with the provided weights.

It will returns a list of RDD.